# 6S+ GPU traces: cannot account for huge MS difference

Tags: ios, performance, opengl-es-2.0, trace

[FAST trace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WHRxc2J-FYOuqxXlq5wMmMMpbblvswgm)

[SLOW trace](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VIgkUNsMmojr_VwydTSlx9PGWI2n5_dO)

These two traces were captured a couple of minutes apart on an iPhone 6S+ on a more or less static menu. One completes in around 8ms, the other in around 14ms. The game will sit quite happily at 7-8ms render time and then, for no apparent reason, rise up to 14ms frame time for a while.

Bafflingly, individual draw calls take almost twice as long in the 'slow' trace as in the 'fast' trace, though I can see no difference between them. The first draw call in particular is noteworthy: a screen-filling quad with a very simple shader that completes in either 1.x ms or 2.x ms, with (so far as I can tell) identical GL settings in force both times.

I can load both traces into xcode and hit 'analyse', and the results are totally reproducible: the slow trace is always slow, and the fast trace is always fast, and I can't see what's different!

Notes: Yes, there are some redundant GL calls generated by our engine. They're the same in both traces, so they're not the focus of this investigation. And yes, the first two calls are a terrible way to achieve a full-screen fill; I've already talked to the designers :) Again: not the focus here because the question is why are those calls taking twice as long in one trace compared to the other.

Answer (score 0):

> The game will sit quite happily at 7-8ms render time and then, for no
>   apparent reason, rise up to 14ms frame time for a while.

I think what you're seeing here is the dynamic energy saving on the device. If you're comfortably hitting your framerate target, then the OS can reduce the clock speed of the CPU/GPU to reduce energy consumption and heat generation.

Unfortunately, this behaviour makes it very difficult to profile performance. I'm not aware of any way to disable this for performance measuring, or to view the current CPU/GPU clock speed (or the number of cores that have been shut down) to confirm the cause of confusing measurements.

I've not looked at your traces, but it's possible that the one you think is slower is actually marginally faster, and comes just under the threshold where the OS decides to half the clock speeds to save energy.

Comment: You might be right. If so, it's very frustrating because as a result of 'clocking down', the device actually drops to 30fps. It's getting its sums wrong.